# Azure B2C integration with Flutter

Tags: azure, flutter, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I have created an app registration within my tenant in B2C which I would like to use in a Flutter app. I've used the [flutter_appauth](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_appauth) package in my Flutter project to access the B2C instance.
However, when attempting to run the application, I receive the following error:

[image]

I double checked my registration, and the information seems correct:

[image]

Within my Adnroid / build.grade file I have the following specified:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
                'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'msauth://com.parasol.app/Bmce%2B9aHdOoVtE7fS3B07tfj7Bc%3D'
        ]
```

I have attempted with just 'com.parasol.app' and 'msauth://com.parasol.app' and I receive the same issue.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the request formation in the first place.

First off, make sure you have the following lines in your build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.parasol.app'
    ]
}
```

As for the app registration, try creating a new app registration as per the following guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-native-application?tabs=app-reg-ga with the only difference that the redirectUri should be

> com.parasol.app://oauthredirect

Double check you've filled the values for clientId, discoveryUrl, scopes properly to form the request.

If you can share the code you use for calling the authorizeAndExchangeCode method with all the parameters it would help understand the issue further.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, did something change in the B2C portal? I can't add com.my.app://oauthredirect under Android redirect URIs. It asks for app name and hash and builds the string for me in the format msauth://com.my.app/hashcode